# insertRowsatIndexPath exception iOS

Tags: ios, insert, rows

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update'

I realize the issue here is that I am trying to add a cell to the tableView but it doesn't want it isn't adding one and I can't figure out why.

```
- (IBAction)addNewIngredient: (id) sender
{
    NSString *newIngredient = [recipe createIngredient];
    [[recipe ingredients]addObject:newIngredient];

    //figure out where that item is in the array
    int lastRow = [[recipe ingredients]indexOfObject: newIngredient];

    NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRow inSection:0];

    NSLog(@"Added a new ingredient!");

    [[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:ip] withRowAnimation:
     UITableViewRowAnimationTop];


}
```

To clarify what I'm trying to do here:

recipe has a property ingredients which is an array of NSStrings.
I am adding an object to the ingredients array (does this automatically increase the array count or do I have to do it manually?)...

Then I'm figuring out where that item is in the array with "int lastRow = [[recipe ingredients]indexOfObject:newIngredient]" 
Then getting an index path to point there.  and then inserting that ingredient into the tableView.

Comment: What is `recipe`? Does it exist?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your exception is that when you insert the row, your `numberOfRowsInSection` will be called again.

At that time, your data needs to be updated so that if you had 0 rows and are inserting one into it, the function returns 1

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  My question is, when I addObject:newIngredient to my array, won't that increase the data count by 1?

Comment: Well, yes, but is that the same array you are checking in your `numberOfRowsInSection` for section 0? Debug it carefully and you'll find the error